# Query caching yii framework

Tags: php, caching, yii

I want to find the total score of the loggedin user & want to cache it.
My code is:

```
$dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_points_log where user_id='.Yii::app()->user->id);    
$sql='SELECT SUM( point) as user_point FROM tbl_points_log left join tbl_action on tbl_action.id = tbl_points_log.action_type_id where user_id='.Yii::app()->user->id;
$user_point = Yii::app()->db->cache(1000, $dependency)->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Is the above code correct?
Do I have to make some changes in the config file to make query caching working? I just added

```
'cache' => array(
     'class' => 'CDbCache'
 ),
```

under components

`var_dump($dependency->getHasChanged());` always evaluates to true, even if i did no changes into database, so why is that?

P.S Dont bother about the SQL statement. Its working!

Comment: It's ok. It should work without problems :)

Comment: How can I be sure if caching is working?

Comment: Turn on debugging and see if the queries are called or not.  If it's cached they will not be called.

Comment: well I used this var_dump($dependency->getHasChanged()); it always evaluates to true, even if i did no changes into database, so why is that?

Answer (score 1):

the best way to find out that query results come from cache or database is that to turn on logging as follow and see the results

```
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ), 
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ), 

            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Well I know that results are fetched from Database as $dependency->getHasChanged() always returning true. So I guess I need to change config for query caching. Any idea?

Comment: it's a better idea to use apc or memcache instead of cdbCache