# how to enable query caching yii framework

Tags: php, caching, yii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query caching yii framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056459/query-caching-yii-framework)

I'm using query caching.

In my config file under components I just added

```
 'cache' => array(
            'class' => 'CDbCache'
        ),
```

But I dont think this is enough as I have checked the results are fetched everytime from the database & not from the cache.

So I think I've to check my configuration. Any help?

Comment: What does the Yii documentation says how it is enabled?

Comment: there is no clear documentation on it. But under CDbConnection there are properties queryCachingDuration & queryCacheID. But I don't get it what it says.

Comment: Please see here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#query-caching - this should be the infomration you're looking for.

Comment: yeah exactly but this part I dont understand "To enable query caching, make sure CDbConnection::queryCacheID refers to the ID of a valid cache application component (it defaults to cache)."

Comment: Scroll to the top of the page and start reading at the top about how data caching genereally works. If that still does not help, then start with the chapter, that should do it then. If still not, you need to be more precise with your question otherwise it's hard to answer.

Comment: well I understand data caching & implemented the same in past too. But for query caching you need to enable it explicitly, thats what it says in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#query-caching. And I just dont get this part "make sure CDbConnection::queryCacheID refers to the ID of a valid cache application component"

Comment: The connection just needs an id and then you need to actually use the caching, just see the example. I would just try using it, and it normally throws an exception if something goes wrong.

Comment: but it cant be just any arbitrary id because it clearly says that ID must refer to valid cache application component. So now what the heck is this "cache application component"?

Comment: I thnk you should update your question because it already changed a lot. That might also attract more Yii profelic users.

Comment: in your case `'cache'` is the ID of the cache component. But you may define another one by _adding_ `'fileCache' => array( 'class' => 'CFileCache' )` to your config, e.g. will have 2 cache components ready to be used. Or you may use `CDbCache` again, but with different settings. So 'valid cache application component' mean 'define `cache` setting or change that if you want to use something else?'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure caching isn't working? Yii will continue to show the same DB queries in the logs even if the caching is working under the hood. Had that trip me up.

The only way to double check is to make sure your cache lasts a long time and then change the data.

Comment: sorry I didnt get you. Can you explain once again how am I going to check if the data are fetched from the cache?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any type of cache invalidation setup, then change some of the data that will be returned.  If the data doesn't come back changed, then your caching is working.