# Get cache with CActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, yii, cactivedataprovider

I was able to store the auery using "CActiveDataProvider" in cache, but it seem like it's not get from the cache, what i am doing wrong?

My config is:

```
'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'CFileCache',
        ),
```

Controller:

```
$dependecy = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(id) FROM {{table}}');

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(Model::model()->cache(3600, $dependecy, 2), array ( 
        'criteria' => array ( 
            'order'=>'date DESC',
        ),
        'pagination' => array ( 
                //'pageSize' => '5',
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: refer this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056459/query-caching-yii-framework

Comment: what i need to do? to add CDBcache to config file?

Comment: Yes. I think you missed to set in config. Please check your config.

Comment: Your configuration looks ok if it is declared in `components`. Does caching work if you remove the dependency?

Comment: How can i do it with out dependency?